# How to return table and additional local variable from oracle stored procedure?

Tags: oracle, plsql

In my stored procedure, I need to generate a report for workbench. I need to take a record from the database tables(by using select query) directly, plus I need to add some manipulated variables. I have to return this resulted collection from procedure as `sys_refcursor`.

For example:
I have table as `emp(id, name)`.
I have variable `job`
Now I want to return (`emp.id`, `emp.name`, `job`) from my procedure.

If you can help it will be great.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy enough to combine a PL/SQL variable with data from a table....

```
Create or replace function get_some
   return sys_refcursor
as
    return_value sys_refcursor;
    l_whatever varchar2(10) := 'JOB';
begin
    open return_value for
        select emp_id, emp_name, l_whatever
        from your_table;
    return return_value;
end;
/
```

I suspect this isn't exactly what you mean.  If that is teh case youi need to *edit your question* to explain more about what you're doing.  Especially what you mean by  "some manipulated vriables *(sic)*".  Providing some sample input and output would be helpful.